# Translate function from R to rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

​Hi! I am using a package in R called `stylo` for stylometric purposes (basically Machine Learning for identification of literary authors based on lexical frequencies), but I am using it in Python using `rpy2`.

In R I would do following:

```
library(stylo)
cosine.delta = function(x){
        # z-scoring the input matrix of frequencies
        x = scale(x)
        # computing cosine dissimilarity
        y = as.dist( x %*% t(x) / (sqrt(rowSums(x^2) %*% t(rowSums(x^2)))) )
        # then, turning it into cosine similarity
        z = 1 - y
        # getting the results
        return(z)
    }
stylo(distance.measure="cosine.delta")
```

Now in Python I know how to call the `library` and the function `stylo`, but I don't know how to define the function `cosine.delta`. Any idea? I have tried things like this:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
R = ro.r
R.library("stylo")
cosinedelta = R.function(x){
        # z-scoring the input matrix of frequencies
        x = scale(x)
        # computing cosine dissimilarity
        y = as.dist( x %*% t(x) / (sqrt(rowSums(x^2) %*% t(rowSums(x^2)))) )
        # then, turning it into cosine similarity
        z = 1 - y
        # getting the results
        return(z)
}
R.stylo(distance.measure="cosinedelta")
```

It says that the `{` is invalid syntax. I have been trying different things (other types of brackets, using

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr 
base = importr('base'))
```

but nothing works I don't know much about neither R or `rpy2` syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run any R code through `rpy2` simply by putting it in a big string, and passing that string as an argument into `R()`. For you, the following should work:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
R = ro.r
R.library("stylo")
R('''
    cosinedelta <- function(x){
        # z-scoring the input matrix of frequencies
        x = scale(x)
        # computing cosine dissimilarity
        y = as.dist( x %*% t(x) / (sqrt(rowSums(x^2) %*% t(rowSums(x^2)))) )
        # then, turning it into cosine similarity
        z = 1 - y
        # getting the results
        return(z)
    }
    ''')
R('stylo(distance.measure=\"cosinedelta\")')
```

This is basically just the R code (with `cosinedelta` instead of `cosine.delta`, not sure whether that matters), wrapped in `''' '''` to make it a multi-line string in python, and `R( )` wrapped around that to execute it as R code.

The last line of code works in a similar way. To be safe, I put backslashes in front of the quotation markers that should be passed straight into R, to make sure that python doesn't try doing anything funny with them and just passes them into R as it should.

For this answer I basically adapted an example in the [documentation](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html#evaluating-r-code), it's probably useful to look through that yourself too.